# Уведомление после добавления товара в корзину

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Добрый день!

Имеется такой код для добавления товара в корзину, как-то можно вывести уведомление при клике на добавить в корзину. Пробовал прописать условие для кнопки, не работает, а только лишь выводится 2 кнопки - добавить в корзину, одна ведет на успешное добавление в корзину, а другая - на вывод этого уведомления.

```
<?php if($_SESSION['total_quantity']):  ?>
     <a class="clickMe" href="?view=addtocart&goods_id=<?=$eyestopper['goods_id']?>"><img class="addtocard-index" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/addcard-index.jpg" alt="Добавить в корзину" /></a>
      <div class="overlay" title="окно"></div>
      <div class="popup">
      <div class="close_order">x</div>
          <p>Товар успешно добавлен в корзину</p>
      </div>                            
<?php endif; ?>
```

Предоставляю ниже код:

```
session_start();

/* ===Сумма заказа в корзине + атрибуты товара===*/
function total_sum($goods, $connection){
    $total_sum = 0;

    $str_goods = implode(',',array_keys($goods));

    $query = "SELECT goods_id, name, price
                FROM goods
                    WHERE goods_id IN ($str_goods)";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['price'] = $row['price'];
        $total_sum += $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty'] * $row['price'];
    }
    return $total_sum;
}
/* ===Сумма заказа в корзине + атрибуты товара===*/

case('addtocart'):
        // добавление в корзину
        $goods_id = abs((int)$_GET['goods_id']);
        addtocart($goods_id);

        $_SESSION['total_sum'] = total_sum($_SESSION['cart'], $connection);

        // кол-во товара в корзине + защита от ввода несуществующего ID товара
        $_SESSION['total_quantity'] = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value){
            if(isset($value['price'])){
                // если получена цена товара из БД - суммируем кол-во
                $_SESSION['total_quantity'] += $value['qty'];
            }else{
                // иначе - удаляем такой ID из сессиии (корзины)
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }
        }
        redirect();
    break;

<h2><span>Корзина</span></h2>
<div>
     <p class="onK">
     ?php if($_SESSION['total_quantity']): ?>
         Товаров в корзине:<br />
         <span><?=$_SESSION['total_quantity']?></span> на сумму <span><?=$_SESSION['total_sum']?></span> руб.
         <img src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/korzinaON.png" class="korzinaON" />
         <a href="#"><img src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/oformit.png" class="oformit" alt="Оформить заказ" /></a>
       <?php else: ?>
            <span class="offK">Корзина пуста</span>
            <img src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/korzinaOFF.png" class="korzinaOFF" />                          
      <?php endif; ?>
      </p>
</div>
```

И подключены:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/workscripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> var query = '<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>';</script>
```

Само уведомление:

```
 <a class="clickMe"href="#">При клике вышло уведомление</a>
```

Функция:

```
var popup = $('.popup'),
    overlay = $('.overlay'),
    timer;
overlay.add($('.close_order',popup)).click(hidePopup);
$('a.clickMe').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    popup.add(overlay).finish().fadeIn(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(hidePopup, 3000);
    });
});
function hidePopup(){
    return popup.add(overlay).fadeOut();
}
```

**jQuery.cookie:**

```
jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
    if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
        options = options || {};
        if (value === null) {
            value = '';
            options.expires = -1;
        }
        var expires = '';
        if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
            var date;
            if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            } else {
                date = options.expires;
            }
            expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
        }
        // CAUTION: Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
        // in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
        // in the packed version for some reason...
        var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
        var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
        var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
        document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
    } else { // only name given, get cookie
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
};
```

А как убрать это при обновлении?

Comment: @DimasikYES, какая-то полная каша, ничего не понятно. Какое условие для кнопки и какие еще две кнопки появляются? В корзину вы добавляете, вроде бы, простым способом (*с перезагрузкой страницы*), но JS о добавлении ничего не знает, а значит и уведомление не выведет.

Comment: @Deonis, согласен, что не знает, сижу думаю, не получается пока( а как ему узнать об этом?

Comment: @Deonis, не понял, то есть мне уведомление то с сообщением не понадобиться? так как :в том же JS, выводите сообщение: "Всё гуд!" и 2 пункт не понял особо.. - "В JS, без перезагрузки, добавляете" . Извините за не понимание(

Comment: @Deonis, дело в том, что я взял его готовый и прикрутил, и то же самое по добавлению товара в корзину (код). Поэтому не знаю, как это записать. Ну, я выше код приложу из jquery-cookie, если время будет, покажите, пожалуйста. Очень-очень буду благодарен за Вашу помощь. Спасибо большое, что помогаете. Не получается( Может, что-то не так делаю, покажите, пожалуйста, лучше:)

Comment: @DimasikYES, код jquery-cookie мне не нужен, я с ним хорошо знаком. А вот с чем не знаком, так это со скриптами, которые вы где-то взяли. Выход вижу такой: оставляете всё как есть, после добавления товара (*на сервере, как у вас*), выводите на экран блок с сообщение, а в JS проверяете - если такой блок на странице присутствует, то скрыть его через 3 секунды или по клику на соответствующую кнопку. Тут уже не нужно ловить событие клика по кнопке (!), а просто смотреть, есть окно сообщения или нет.

Comment: @Deonis, Не получается( Может, что-то не так делаю, покажите, пожалуйста лучше:)

Comment: [Смотрите по ссылке][1]. Надеюсь, что вы понимаете, что это только **пример** и копипастиь его не нужно? Нажимаете "Run", "Добавить в корзину", смотрите в код, разбераетесь что к чему, пишите **нормальную** реализацию в реальном проекте.

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0res-0wpy